# in python ,use redis-py with multiprocessing module , why each process is different fd?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, redis, redis-py

in python ,use redis-py with multiprocessing module , why each process is different fd ?

test code:

```
    # xiaorui.cc

import time
import multiprocessing

import redis

r = redis.Redis(host='127.0.0.1', port=6379, db=0)

def func(msg):
    for i in xrange(30):
        time.sleep(1)
        print r.keys()
    return "done " + msg


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    result = []
    for i in xrange(4):
        msg = "hello %d" %(i)
        result.append(pool.apply_async(func, (msg, )))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    for res in result:
        print res.get()
    print "Sub-process(es) done."
```

test result:

```
[ruifengyun@xiaorui.cc ~]$ ps aux f|grep a.py
508      11704  5.0  0.0 421096 11664 pts/11   Sl+  17:50   0:00  |           \_ python a.py
508      11709  0.0  0.0 193760  7464 pts/11   S+   17:50   0:00  |               \_ python a.py
508      11710  0.0  0.0 193760  7468 pts/11   S+   17:50   0:00  |               \_ python a.py
508      11711  0.0  0.0 193760  7468 pts/11   S+   17:50   0:00  |               \_ python a.py
508      11712  0.0  0.0 193760  7476 pts/11   S+   17:50   0:00  |               \_ python a.py
508      11720  0.0  0.0 103248   832 pts/12   S+   17:50   0:00              \_ grep a.py
[ruifengyun@xiaorui.cc ~]$ sudo lsof -p 11709|grep 6379
python  11709 ruifengyun    4u  IPv4 4173927407      0t0        TCP localhost:51433->localhost:6379 (ESTABLISHED)
[ruifengyun@xiaorui.cc ~]$ sudo lsof -p 11710|grep 6379
python  11710 ruifengyun    4u  IPv4 4173927417      0t0        TCP localhost:51435->localhost:6379 (ESTABLISHED)
[ruifengyun@xiaorui.cc ~]$ sudo lsof -p 11711|grep 6379
python  11711 ruifengyun    4u  IPv4 4173927411      0t0        TCP localhost:51434->localhost:6379 (ESTABLISHED)
[ruifengyun@xiaorui.cc ~]$ sudo lsof -p 11712|grep 6379
python  11712 ruifengyun    4u  IPv4 4173927416      0t0        TCP localhost:51436->localhost:6379 (ESTABLISHED)
```

**why is redis conn fd of each process different?   In my cognitive  , only create redis connect in lazy mode, different redis fd is emerged.**

and, all child processes are shared r object (redis conect fd).

Answer (score 0):

Each process needs to connect to Redis individually.  And a single outbound port will only be used by a single process.  So each process gets its own port.